# SSL Library Error: X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I installed a new SSL certificate signed by our own Certificate Authority. Apache will not start, with the error:

> SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate
>   routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

I have verified the key and cert Do match, so the error message is wrong. I have tred with and without the `SSLCaCertificateFile` directive. How do I fix this?

```
diff <(openssl rsa -in KEY -modulus -noout) <(openssl x509 -in CERT -modulus -noout)
```

produces no output, which I belive is corect.

The commands used to make the certificates:

Create a CA:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096
```

Self sign the CA

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key my.key -out  my.crt
```

Generate a server key

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
```

Create a csr for the new key

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

Create a certificate from a CSR:

```
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA my.crt -CAkey my.key -out server.crt -days 1820
```

Comment: What did you do to verify that the public and private key files match?

Comment: I used an online tool that checks to see if they match.

Comment: I just created a new key, csr and signed a new cert. Same error.

Comment: I just started over with a brand new CA, new server certs and everything, and still get this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had more than one vhost file with SSL enabled.

The second host I didn't care about matching the domain because it was for private use. If you have more than one vhost with ssl on a single IP, you have to update the certificates in all of them at the same time, apparently.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you supply all the chain of certificates. You can also try to combine them in one .pem as described [here](https://itgala.xyz/apache-ssl-error-certificate-routinesx509-key-values-mismatch/)